# Why does Stack Overflow keep deleting my comments?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I encountered the RandomForestClassifier non-reproducible problem. Someone has posted and solved this problem: ([Python sklearn RandomForestClassifier non-reproducible results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433920/python-sklearn-randomforestclassifier-non-reproducible-results/69453946#69453946)).

[image: Comment's Screenshot]

So I left a comment asking for the details of his solution. But why do the moderators keep deleting my comments?

[image: The hidden post's screenshoot]

Comment: You are posting comments in Answers section. Don't do that. It is mean only for answering. When you reach 50 reputation points you will be able to post comments.

Comment: And what you wrote **isn't a comment**, **it's an ANSWER**. Answers should answer the question not to ask questions. Wait until you've 50 reputation points to be able to write a comment.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum. You can visit [help] to learn more about rules here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to better understand what SO actually is ("a library of detailed answers to every question about programming"). It's not a discussion forum and answers should be answers to the question else they will get deleted. Also, comments are different from answers and they too have a specific, narrow [purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have a new question, don't post an answer but a new question after consulting the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: `It is really a bad experience using StackOverflow today!` It probably is for everyone that didn't read the tour. For example, lots of things are different from discussion forums: MCVEs have to be in the question, "thanks" is subject to deletion, ask similar questions as a new question, etc. There are really a lot of rules, but they aren't rocket science.

Comment: The general gist is: don't use the site as you want, use it as intended. To be able to use the site as intended, you will need to read the house rules first.

Comment: Your comment wasn’t deleted.  You submitted an answer, which was deleted, because it failed to reach the minimum requirements for an answer.  One of those requirements is that it not be a comment. Stop submitting commentary as an answer and your answers will stop being deleted

Answer (score 2):

You are posting comments in the Answers section of the website: that zone is only for answering!
When you reach 50 (+40 reputation) reputation points you will be able to post comments.

This may help: [Six simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast)

Comment: This post is just a modified (but not improved) copy of [Dalija's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412034/why-does-stack-overflow-keep-deleting-my-comments#comment871391_412034) without attribution.